# How to bind Dropdownlist in asp.net using jquery?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net application,in that I have to bind dropdownlist with country_names using jquery. I have used following code:-

```
[WebMethod]
    public static CountryDetails[] BindDatatoDropdown()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=RIZ-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Sandeep;Integrated Security=True;");
    conn.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    List<CountryDetails> details = new List<CountryDetails>();

    // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CountryID,CountryName FROM Country", con);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CountryID,CountryName FROM Country", conn);
    da.Fill(dt);
    foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
    {
        CountryDetails country = new CountryDetails();
        country.CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(dtrow["CountryId"].ToString());
        country.CountryName = dtrow["CountryName"].ToString();
        details.Add(country);
    }
    return details.ToArray();
}

public class CountryDetails
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

but it does not work,when the control goes to conn.open(), it shows an error in window,the error only shows "The page at localhost says: Error"kindly help me.Thanx

Comment: try putting a try and catch in the web method and post the exception error

Comment: I did it by own.Actually the database was online and server was slow.That's why it was showing that error.

Comment: so now its working well and good..

Comment: yes,it is working well and good now.